# Prove that $p_1 \le \sqrt{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n = {p_1}^{a_1} \dots {p_k}^{a_k}$. Prove that $p_1 \le \sqrt n$.

It seems intuitive, but is there a formal proof to this?

Context:

[image]

Comment: What happens when $n = p$?

Comment: @DERPYPENGUIN this edit doesn't change anything for the problem Jacky Chong raised or I did.

Comment: @DERPYPENGUIN you might want $n$ to be composite. Then everything should go through.

Comment: Need to show earlier in the proof when n and the p's were defined.  I assume this assumes p_1 is the least prime and there is more than one prime factor.

Comment: I suppose it's sufficient for the purpose here to say $p_1$ is the least prime factor, but my inner Sheldon wants to see it specified that $p_1 < p_2 < \ldots < p_k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $n = p_1^{\alpha_1} p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots p_{k}^{\alpha_k}$, then
\begin{align}
p_1 \leq \sqrt{p_1p_2} \leq \sqrt{n} 
\end{align}
where $p_1<p_2<\ldots <p_k$.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree, what if $p_1 = 7$ and $p_2=2$? We can easily see that $\sqrt{14}>3$ since $9<14$.

**Edit (following op's likely edit of original question):** Since $a_1\ge 2$ and $p_1$ is the least prime, just note that if $p_1\ge\sqrt{n}$ then $p_1^2>n$. But then $p_1^{a_1-2}p_2^{a_2}\ldots p_k^{a_k}\ge 1$ so we conclude that $n>n$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

This is only true if you specify $p_1 <p_ {i} $ for all $i>1$. And that $n $ is itself not prime.

Of course, if you specify that, it is trivial.

if $n = p_1*p_1^{a_1-1}*\prod_{i=2}^k p_i^{a_i}$ then $p_1 \le p_1^{a_1-1}*\prod_{i=2}^k p_i^{a_i} $ so $p_1*p_1\le p_1* p_1^{a_1-1}*\prod_{i=2}^k  p_i^{a_i}$ and $\sqrt {p_1*p_1}\le \sqrt {p_1* p_1^{a_1-1}*\prod_{i=2}^k p_i^{a_i}} $.

And if you don't specify that, of course, it is not true.